# Как использовать в Postgresql одновременно AVG и AGE?

Tags: sql

У меня есть SQL запрос,  который получает время ответа на задачу.

(вычисляется как :  время создания задачи - время комментария)

```
select jiraaction.author,actionbody,  jiraissue.pkey, age (jiraaction.created, jiraissue.created)as time_response
from jiraaction 
inner join jiraissue on jiraaction.issueid = jiraissue.id 
where jiraissue.pkey like '%-26578%'
```

Проблема в том, что дальше к этому выводу я не могу применить функцию - "AVG" (для того чтобы вычистить среднее время ответа. )

Как эти функции правильно сопоставить ? ("AGE" И "AVG")

А когда делаю так :

```
select jiraaction.author,actionbody,  jiraissue.pkey, avg(age(jiraaction.created, jiraissue.created) as time_response) as avg_time_response
from jiraaction
inner join jiraissue on jiraaction.issueid = jiraissue.id 
where jiraissue.pkey like '%-26578%'
```

sql начинает ругаться :

SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "as"

Любая помощь важна! Спасибо!

Comment: Так а зачем вам `as time_response`?

Comment: Среднее значение предполагает вычисление для группы значений. У Вас группировки нет. Среднее чего хотите вычислить?

Comment: @ValNik Спасибо! Да, действительно , вы правы!